# How to guarantee the sorting in a spark Dataset while doing foreach

Tags: apache-spark

i find the behavior very strange from Spark when doing a sort and foreach on a Dataset. It seems like it's executing the foreach out of order. How do I get it to guarantee the order without collecting it into a List?

```
dailyData.sort("diff_seconds").foreach(row1 -> {
                System.out.println("diff_seconds: " + row1.getAs("diff_seconds"));
            });

diff_seconds: 62489
diff_seconds: 62493
diff_seconds: 62166 <------
diff_seconds: 62494
diff_seconds: 62495
```

Answer (score 0):

Map Reduce uses parallelizable operation to speed the computation up.
The order can not be guaranteed under such mechanism.
You should simply keep the sort key after the operation and sort it after collecting the result.